# r/m8 operand being interpreted as r/m32 operand by disassembler

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, intel, disassembly

Pretty much I've been working on my (basic) disassembler, everything works fine but after disassembling some bytes I noticed something weird:

This is the set of instructions I'm trying to decode:

```
unsigned char Data[] = {
        0xF0, 0xF0, 0x55, 0xFF, 0x89, 0xE5, 0xB8, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x48, 0xC3, 0xF4,
        0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0x66, 0xE7, 0xFF, 0xF0
    };
```

and this is the Disassembler's output:

[image]

The 00 00 (ADD [AL], AL) is weird to me: moving the value of al into the address at al doesn't seem right. I am wondering if my output is correct...

I also tested it against defuse.ca's online disassembler, and this is what I got from there:

```
Disassembly:
0:  f0 f0 55                lock lock push ebp
3:  ff 89 e5 b8 04 00       dec    DWORD PTR [ecx+0x4b8e5]
9:  00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
b:  40                      inc    eax
c:  48                      dec    eax
d:  c3                      ret
e:  f4                      hlt
f:  cc                      int3
10: cc                      int3
11: cc                      int3
12: 66 e7 ff                out    0xff,ax
15: f0                      lock
```

Comment: What operation mode are you disassembling in (16, 32, or 64 bit mode)?  Also note that the data you sent to the online disassembler is different than the one you disassembled offline.  Lastly, do not post pictures of text please!

Comment: I am disassembling in 32bit mode and yes I noticed now. I don't know why though, I just pasted it inside the online disassembler straight from the code, and the data has not been changed when I tested online.

Comment: Anyway, the online tool's disassemble is correct.  Redundant prefixes are not forbidden, but `lock` on a `push` instruction is undefined.

Comment: @fuz I also noticed that, but why is ADD using [EAX] instead of [AL] even if ADD's (00) first operand is an r/m8? Why is an r/m32 operand being used instead?

Comment: the operand size is independent of the address size.  `[eax]` means “memory at address `eax`.”  It doesn't say how much bytes are accessed at that address.  Some assemblers allow you to write, say, `byte ptr [eax]` to clarify the operand size.  The address size (defaults to 32 bit in 32 bit mode, regardless of operand size) can be overridden with a `67` prefix, but note that `[ax]` is not a valid addressing mode.

Comment: `add [eax], al` is an r/m8 memory operand.  You can tell the operand-size from the register operand (AL), not from the address-size used in the addressing mode for a memory operand.

Comment: If you cross-check your disassembler with NDISASM, beware of some bugs which I have discovered in NDISASM version 2.14rc15
https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=2463.msg11129#msg11129